# Create multiple new linear layout with unique ID in root layout programiticaly in andriod

Tags: android

Question: On click of button, i want to add new LinearLayout under main Layout with unique ID, so that, i could refer child layout layout later.
    This is my activity class. On click on Add button, new linear layout should create and get added to main linear layout. Each new layout should have unique ID, so that, this new ID will refer later.

```
public class CreateEventFragment extends Fragment{
    private ListView listView;
    private EditText createEventEtEventName,createEventEtQuestion;
    private AboutUsAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<MyPojoObj> obj;
    private String jsonAboutus;
    private ProgressBar createEventPb;
    private RadioGroup createEventRadioGroupEventType;
    private RadioButton createEventRadioType1,createEventRadioType2;
    private LinearLayout createEventLL;
    private Button createEventBtnAdd,createEventBtnSubmit;
    private int id=0;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(Variable.sop)System.out.println("CreateEventFragment.onCreateView()");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_event, container,false);
        obj=new ArrayList<MyPojoObj>();
        createEventBtnAdd = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.createEventBtnAdd);
        createEventBtnSubmit = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.createEventBtnSubmit);
        createEventEtEventName=(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.createEventEtEventName);
        createEventRadioType1=(RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.createEventRadioType1);
        createEventRadioType2=(RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.createEventRadioType2);*/
        createEventLL = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.createEventLL);

        createEventEtEventName.setText("EventName");
        getMinutes());
        createEventBtnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                actionAddNewEvent();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    void actionAddNewEvent(){

        id=id+1;

        int left=5;
        int top=1;
        int right=1;
        int bottom=0;

        int leftMargin=5;
        int topMargin=5;
        int rightMargin=5;
        int bottomMargin=5;

        int childId=0;

      LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
        (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
      ll.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.feed_bg));
      ll.setLayoutParams(lp);
      ll.setId(id);
      ll.setTag(id);    
      createEventLL.addView(ll);
      Drawable img = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.questions );
      img.setBounds( 0, 0, 55, 55 );

        //question edit text
      EditText createEventEtQuestion = new EditText(getActivity());
      createEventEtQuestion.setLayoutParams(lp);
      createEventEtQuestion.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
      createEventEtQuestion.setFocusable(true);
      createEventEtQuestion.setCompoundDrawables( img, null, null, null );
      createEventEtQuestion.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.border_1 ));
      createEventEtQuestion.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.feed_item_bg));

      RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup (getActivity());
      rg.setId(500+id);

      RadioButton radioButton1 = new RadioButton(getActivity());
      radioButton1.setText("True/False");
      radioButton1.setId(100000+id);//set radiobutton id and store it somewhere
      radioButton1.setTextSize(12);
      RadioGroup.LayoutParams params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

      RadioButton radioButton2 = new RadioButton(getActivity());
      radioButton2.setText("Yes/No");
      radioButton2.setTextSize(12);
      radioButton2.setId(100001+id);//set radiobutton id and store it somewhere

      rg.addView(radioButton1, params);
      rg.addView(radioButton2, params);

      // Add Type Title
      TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
      //tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
      tv.setText("Answer Type");
      tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
      tv.setTextSize(12);
      tv.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);

      LinearLayout.LayoutParams rmlp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
        (200, 50);

      Button removeBtn = new Button(getActivity());
      //tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
      removeBtn.setText("Delete Question:"+id);
      removeBtn.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
      removeBtn.setLayoutParams(rmlp);
      //removeBtn.setId(id);
      removeBtn.setTextSize(9);
      removeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                actionRemoveQuestion(arg0);
            }
        });

      // draw line
      View v = new View(getActivity());
      v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
       LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,   
       2
      ));
      v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));


      ll.addView(createEventEtQuestion);
      ll.addView(tv);   
      ll.addView(rg);
      ll.addView(removeBtn);
      ll.addView(v);

    }

    void actionRemoveQuestion(View view){
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), view.getId()+" | "+view.getParent(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //View namebar = view.findViewById(view.getId());
        //ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) namebar.getParent();

        if (true) {
          final LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout) createEventLL.findViewById(id);
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "cCount:"+child.getChildCount()+" | cID:"+child.getId()+" |" +
            " pCount:"+createEventLL.getChildCount()+" | cTAG:"+child.getTag()+" | pID:"+createEventLL.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you dont need an unique id, you already have the references to those layouts, dont you?

Comment: each layout holding delete button. on click of delete button, i want that layout should get deleted

Comment: good, then remove that layout (see `ViewGroup` documentation)

Comment: can you help me with the sample program, if you could

Comment: did you see `ViewGroup` docs?

Comment: going through that only now, thanks a lot.. do let me know, if we would any other options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an onClickListener to the button to generate a new LinearlyLayout. But I get your problem you will not be able to reference it when you create another child Layout to edit or remove it.

A better way would be to use a LinearLayout array to dynamically generate LinearLayout so that you can reference them and use them later.

The code maybe similar to :

```
LinearLayout [ ] linearLayout;
```

At the declaration
And in the onClickListener add :

```
linearLayout[ ] = new LinearLayout[ ];
```

This could better be done in a for loop as it increases a counter everytime the button is clicked.

I think this approach should work.